# javascript de-anonymizing a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, anonymous-function

really basic stuff here. I'd like to give a click function a name and assign some parameters to it. The goal is code reusability such that I can write only one generic function for common tasks such as for enabling users to delete various data.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fz5ZT/38/) to show you what I mean.

And here's that code:

the HTML:

```
<button>delete this</button>
<div data-id="3" class="delete">something bad</div>
<div data-id="4" class="delete">something else bad</div>
```

and the JS:

```
// this function would be loaded on my site's template and therefore would be available across my entire site.
function deleteThis(data_id){           
   $('button').on('click', 'button', function(){
      $('div[data-id="'+data_id+'"]').hide();  
   });
}  

var clicked_id=3;
function deleteThis(clicked_id); 
// this function would be called on the various pages where users can delete things and this variable, clicked_id, would be assigned=3 by the user's action on that page.
```

How do I give this button click event a name?

**update** thanks all! the `$('button')` should have been `$(document.body)` or the button's parent element. It works if you make that simple change. You can also do it as Michael Buen suggests below.

Comment: Your code in the jsFiddle is different from that here. You've made your function name such that it is only available inside the function itself. Get rid of the outer `( )()` part of the function. Also, you're using the event delegation version of `on`. This means that the `button` clicked only runs if it has a *descendant* button that was clicked. Obviously you don't have a button inside a button.

Comment: ...updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/fz5ZT/40/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just refactor your code, put the delete functionality on its own function

```
<button>delete this</button>
<div data-id="3" class="delete">something bad</div>
<div data-id="4" class="delete">something else bad</div>
​

$('button').on('click', function() { deleteImmediately(3) });

function deleteImmediately(id) { -- refactored code
    $('div[data-id='+id+']').hide();  
}​
```

Live test: http://jsfiddle.net/e2kuj/2/

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddler, the `(function deleteThis(){})()` is making it private and you are trying to access it as a global!

Answer (score 1):

It was almost right. I updated it -> http://jsfiddle.net/fz5ZT/41/

```
function deleteThis(id){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('div[data-id="'+id+'"]').hide();  
    });    
};
deleteThis(3);​
```

Comment: Please post your solution here instead of only on a different site. This way it's available for future readers in case the link breaks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding events. deleteThis only makes sense if it's in the handler.

corrected HTML: (don't use custom attributes for referencing HTML - They're slower)

```
<button>delete this</button>
<div id="del_3" class="delete">something bad</div>
<div id="del_4" class="delete">something else bad</div>
```

JS: (untested)

```
var deleteTargetId = 'del_3'; //clicked_id renamed for clarity

function deleteThis(targetId){
    $('#'+targetId).remove(); //removes rather than hides the html
}

$('button').click( function(){
    deleteThis(deleteTargetId);
} );
```

Now you could swap deleteTarget and the HTML with that ID would get yoinked.

However, if this is homework, I'm wondering if you understand the assignment. The var named 'clicked_id' suggests the idea is to click the divs to make them disappear and use delegation. That one's easy.

You'll need to understand event delegation and event bubbling to see what's going on here. Basically when something is clicked, the event then fires on the parent element and then that parent element's parent element, all the way up to the HTML tag. This happens with all events and doesn't cause the trouble you might think because containers are rarely assigned listeners for events. Links and buttons are more typically end point nodes or at most contain a span or an image. Usually when bubbling causes a problem it's because somebody's doing something awful with HTML or they should've been using delegation in the first place.

'on' is the new piss-poor name for the once appropriately named and less confusion-prone 'delegate' jquery method. Essentially anything in the body with the class 'delete' triggers the handler. We don't care about the ID since the idea is to kill the div that was clicked and 'this' gives us a reference to it. This is unusual behavior for JQ, since most methods would have 'this' point at the 'body' but it's obviously a more useful thing to point at for event delegation.

```
$('body').on('click', '.delete', function(e){
    $(this).remove(); //this refers to the originally clicked element
} );
//note: not the solution you asked for, but possibly the one you needed.
```

Comment: thanks Erik, ultimately there will be multiple pieces of data connected to the click event (e.g., url for $.post()) that is why i want to have parameters and not just use `$(this)`, but thanks for clarifying many concepts for me,

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `$('button').on('click', 'button', clickHandler);` to reference the `clickHandler` function.

I am big fan of such things since apart from being reusable it has the following advantages.

- I will be able to just send across a patch in case there's a bug in the clickHandler
- Someone can augment my method which is not possible with anonymous methods
- Readable, and also useful to see the stack trace in case of errors

Hope that helps.

**Update:**

```
function clickHandler(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    // ... handler code
}
```

Comment: hi g13n, thanks for the tips, can you show me what the clickHandler function would look like in my case?

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the element in a different way:

```
  $('button').on('click', function(){
      $(this).next("div").remove();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fz5ZT/46/

Comment: hi Raminson, can you show me how that code would look in my case? This is new territory for me.